# Able to switch printers via HTML, Flash, or anything else?

Tags: web-applications, printing, point-of-sale

I'm working on converting an inventory management app from desktop to a web-app.  The desktop app generates multiple formats of printouts:

- mailing labels to a Dymo printer
- general 8.5 x 11 printouts
- and thermal receipt printouts to a Star printer (usually 72mm wide x 200mm long)

Half the solution to ensure accurate printing is to generate PDFs; **however, is there a way to change printers on the browser/client side through a web page?**  I'd like it to be as cross-platform as possible.

I don't think it is, but I'd like to reach out to developers smarter than I am!

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in java, but not javascript, and i don't now about flash but i doubt it.